# MXNet initialization error on label variable

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

When I call `module.fit()` I'm getting an error
`ValueError: Unknown initialization pattern for labelidx`.
The symbol "labelidx" is the name I'm using for my label data -- I didn't want to use `softmax_label` because I'm not using softmax output, but that seems to be the default for a lot of thigns.  It seems to be trying to initialize `labelidx` as a parameter, which is a mistake.  How can I tell it this is an input not a learned parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out.

When constructing the `Module` object, you need to tell it the names of the data (`data_names`) and labels (`label_names`).  Each of these should be a list of string names.  By default `data_names=('data',), label_names=('softmax_label',),`  Otherwise it assumes everything else is learned parameters and will try to initialize them, leading to this error.  Docs: http://mxnet.io/api/python/module.html#mxnet.module.module.Module

So in my case it needs `Module(label_names=('labelidx',), ...)`